# Printing Infopath form 2010(.xml) in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: printing, microsoft-infopath, sharepoint-2010

My question is related to printing an Infopath 2010 form in Sharepoint 2010.I designed an Infopath 2010 form in Infopath Designer 2010 and published it to a form library in Sharepoint 2010.The end user fill the form and store it in .xml format in the document library.Now I would like to print the form filled by the end user? Any Ideas or suggestion about the above scenario?Please consider both browser based forms and normal forms

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider converting the InfoPath form to PDF as part of an automated workflow (or manual action) and send that to the browser for printing.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/batch-print-infopath-forms-using-pdf.html) that I wrote on the topic, it requires the use of a third party tool that I worked on as well.

Additional InfoPath based posts on this topic [can be found here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/search/label/InfoPath).

Comment: ITs not about workflow.I am just publishing the infopath form to the document library and it is there in xml format.I would like to print them with a click with out previewing it on screen.Directly the print dialogue should appear?Please suggest me in this way? providing code is appreciated?

Comment: Don't be scared off by 'workflow', it is just the first step to quickly convert it to PDF. Alternatively you could create a hyperlink to quickly download a PDF version. It is still up to the user to then click the print button, see http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/converting-any-file-to-pdf-using-simple.html.

Comment: @SurendraJ: Think of the 'workflow' like a macro, with options to feed it steroids.  The workflow solution can even print them, package them up and email it to you with a bow on top.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found an answer but here is a practical answer

http://arcemise.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/sharepoint-2010-infopath-print-button/#comment-56

Comment: Hello @LoonRanger! Welcome to SuperUser. It'll be cool if you can elaborate a bit of the contents in the attached link instead of just answering with a link :)